# Why does an element appear twice after transformation?

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I'm working with Perl and XSL. I try to change value of `<Interval>` to some number in an XML file. My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Interval>5</Interval>
</Config>
```

My XSL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Config/Interval">
<xsl:element name="PollingInterval">
    <xsl:element name="Interval">77</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that my output has the element `<Interval>` twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Interval><Interval>77</Interval></Interval>
</Config>
```

Please help.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation of the problem and a complete and simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that my output has the
>   element  twice:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> 
> <Config> 
>     <Enabled>false</Enabled> 
>     <Interval><Interval>77</Interval></Interval>
>
> </Config>
> ```

**Not true!**

The output when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document is:

```
<Config>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <PollingInterval><Interval>77</Interval></PollingInterval>
</Config>
```

**In case you want to get rid of either element, simply remove the corresponding `<xsl:element>`** instruction.

**For example**: Removing `<xsl:element name="PollingInterval">` the transformation becomes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Config/Interval">
      <xsl:element name="Interval">77</xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and the result from applying it on the provided XML document is**:

```
<Config>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Interval>77</Interval>
</Config>
```

**I recommend to simplify the transformation further and to match on the text node child of `Interval`. This is possibly the shortest and simplest solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Interval/text()">
      <xsl:text>77</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Config>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Interval>5</Interval>
</Config>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<Config>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Interval>77</Interval>
</Config>
```

In case you have many `Interval` elements and want only to replace the value `5` by `77` then the only template except the identity rule should be:

```
<xsl:template match="Interval/text()[.=5]">
  <xsl:text>77</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Interval/text()">77</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Config>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Interval>77</Interval>
</Config>
```

**Note**: If you post the other input sample and describe the binding, we could show you how to extract the new number.

**EDIT**: Shorter.